# Merge sort visualisation using recursion and Promises

Tags: javascript, sorting, recursion, promise, p5.js

I've written a merge sort visualisation in p5.js which shows the steps of merge sort. This works fine as a sequential visualisation, but I'd quite like to show this as a true representation, where you can see each part of the array being sorted at the same time (with multiple sections being visualised sorting at the same time, to truly reflect the recursion). The code itself is relatively simple:

```
    // Split the array recursively
    let mid = Math.floor((right + left) / 2);

    if (right - left < 1) {
        return;
    }
    
    // My attempt to visualise this properly
    await Promise.all([mergeSortSlice(array, left, mid), mergeSortSlice(array, mid + 1, right)]);
    
    // THIS WORKS, but only for sequential sorting
    // await mergeSortSlice(array, left, mid);
    // await mergeSortSlice(array, mid + 1, right)

   // Putting sleep(200) here also works, but doesn't show the steps of the sort as they are happening, just the result of each stage of the sort.

    leftCounter = 0;
    rightCounter = 0;
    l = left;
    r = mid + 1;
    valuesStartIndex = l;
    let leftArray = array.slice(left, r);
    let rightArray = array.slice(r, right + 1);

    while (rightCounter < rightArray.length && leftCounter < leftArray.length) {
        if (leftArray[leftCounter] < rightArray[rightCounter]) {
            array.splice(l + rightCounter, 1);
            array.splice(valuesStartIndex, 0, leftArray[leftCounter]);
            l++;
            leftCounter++;
            valuesStartIndex++;
            await sleep(200);

        } else {
            array.splice(r, 1);
            array.splice(valuesStartIndex, 0, rightArray[rightCounter]);
            r++;
            rightCounter++;
            valuesStartIndex++;
            await sleep(200);
        }
    }
```

The problem with using `Promise.all` is that the split parts of the array are getting mixed up, I believe due to the recursion? This is resulting in the array not getting sorted properly.

My timeout function:

```
async function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

The setup function and draw loop:

```
let values = [50, 10, 80, 56, 30, 25, 15]

function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 190);
    frameRate(60);
    mergeSort(values)
}

function draw() {
    rectWidth = 10;
    background(23);
    stroke(0);
    fill(255);

    for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        rect(i * rectWidth, height - values[i], rectWidth, values[i]);
    }
}
```

The combination of async functions and recursion makes it difficult for me to come up with a solution for this. Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: recursions don't run in parallel, there's always a single worker thread. Your algorithm is naturally depth-first, so the right branch doesn't even start until the left one is fully complete. Promise.all won't change anything about that.

Comment: Interesting, so could you explain why `Promise.all` is changing the outcome of the sort? And would I have to rewrite my algorithm to achieve the functionality I want - is it not possible to work with what I've got here?

Comment: I guess a simpler option would be a "fake" visualization, that is, perform the algorithm as it is, recording steps in a separate array, rearrange that array to imitate parallel processing and visualize it.

Comment: Perfect, I'll give this a go. Thank you!

Comment: It's unclear where you are calling `draw`. Also your function appears to use global variables, which is bound to fail with multiple concurrent calls.

Comment: @georg there's nothing wrong with having concurrent asynchronous calls, be they recursive or not.

Comment: @Bergi, in p5 draw is called continuously throughout the running of the program. Does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were actually very close to having a working solution. Your issue is that you are creating a bunch of global variables inside your `mergeSortSlice` function:

```
  // These were all missing the let keyword
  // And were therefore either assigning or implicitly declaring
  // globally scoped variables.
  let leftCounter = 0;
  let rightCounter = 0;
  let l = left;
  let r = mid + 1;
  let valuesStartIndex = l;
  let leftArray = array.slice(left, r);
  let rightArray = array.slice(r, right + 1);
```

When two instances of a function invocation being run as part of a Promise each of which await on timeouts, their execution is going to be interleaved (which you want so you can graphically represent the theoretical parallelism). However, when those functions alter global variables this is a classic shared memory multi-threading bug.

Here's an adaptation of your code with the bug fixed, highlighting added, and a slightly different delay strategy:

```js
function merge_sort(p) {
  const Mode = {
    Shuffling: 0,
    Sorting: 1
  };
  const spacing = 5;

  let array = [...Array(40)].map((_, i) => i);
  let highlights = [];
  let itemWidth;
  let itemHeight;

  let currentMode = Mode.Shuffling;
  let iterator;

  let frameRate = 8;

  let redrawPromise;
  let signalRedraw;

  p.setup = function() {
    p.createCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight);
    p.frameRate(frameRate * 5);

    itemWidth = (p.width - (spacing * (array.length + 1))) / array.length;
    itemHeight = p.height - spacing * 2;

    iterator = shuffle();
    initRedrawPromise();
  };

  function initRedrawPromise() {
    redrawPromise =
      new Promise(resolve => {
        signalRedraw = resolve;
      });
    redrawPromise.then(() => initRedrawPromise());
  }

  p.draw = function() {
    p.background('white');

    // draw
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (highlights[i]) {
        p.fill(highlights[i]);
      } else {
        p.fill('blue');
      }

      let fractionalHeight = (array[i] + 1) / array.length;
      let pixelHeight = fractionalHeight * itemHeight;
      p.rect(
        (i + 1) * spacing + i * itemWidth,
        spacing + (itemHeight - pixelHeight),
        itemWidth,
        pixelHeight
      );
    }

    signalRedraw();

    if (currentMode === Mode.Shuffling) {
      // update
      let next = iterator.next();
      if (next.value) {
        // Done suffle, switch to sort
        currentMode = Mode.Sorting;
        p.frameRate(frameRate);
        sort().then(() => {
          // switch back to shuffling
          currentMode = Mode.Shuffling;
          p.frameRate(frameRate * 5);
          iterator = shuffle();
        });
      }
    }
  };

  p.keyPressed = function(e) {
    if (e.key === 'ArrowRight' || e.key === 'ArrowUp') {
      frameRate++;
      p.frameRate(frameRate);
    } else if (e.key === 'ArrowLeft' || e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
      frameRate = Math.max(0, frameRate - 1);
      p.frameRate(frameRate);
    }
  }

  // shuffle the array. yield false for each step where the array is not yet shuffled. yield true once the array is shuffled.
  function* shuffle() {
    // for each position in the array (except the last position),
    //   if the chosen item is not the current item, swap the two items.
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
      highlight(i);
      yield false;

      let j = randomInt(i, array.length);
      if (j !== i) {
        highlight(i, j);
        yield false;

        swap(i, j);

        highlight(j, i);
        yield false;
      } else {
        highlight(i);
        yield false;
      }
    }

    yield true;
  }

  function sort() {
    highlights = [];
    return sortSlice(0, array.length - 1);
  }

  async function sortSlice(left, right) {
    if (right - left < 1) {
      return;
    }

    // Split the array recursively
    let mid = Math.floor((right + left) / 2);

    await Promise.all([sortSlice(left, mid), sortSlice(mid + 1, right)]);

    for (let ix = left; ix <= right; ix++) {
      highlights[ix] = undefined;
    }

    let leftCounter = 0;
    let rightCounter = 0;
    let l = left;
    let r = mid + 1;
    let valuesStartIndex = l;
    let leftArray = array.slice(left, r);
    let rightArray = array.slice(r, right + 1);

    while (rightCounter < rightArray.length && leftCounter < leftArray.length) {
      if (leftArray[leftCounter] < rightArray[rightCounter]) {
        array.splice(l + rightCounter, 1);
        array.splice(valuesStartIndex, 0, leftArray[leftCounter]);
        highlights[valuesStartIndex] = 'green';
        highlights[r] = 'red';
        l++;
        leftCounter++;
        valuesStartIndex++;
      } else {
        array.splice(r, 1);
        array.splice(valuesStartIndex, 0, rightArray[rightCounter]);
        highlights[valuesStartIndex] = 'green';
        r++;
        rightCounter++;
        valuesStartIndex++;
        highlights[l + rightCounter] = 'red';
      }

      // at each merge step wait for a redraw that shows this step
      await redrawPromise;
      highlights[valuesStartIndex - 1] = 'gray';
      for (let ix = valuesStartIndex; ix <= right; ix++) {
        highlights[ix] = undefined;
      }
    }
  }

  function swap(i, j) {
    const tmp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = tmp;
  }

  function randomInt(lowerBound, upperBound) {
    return lowerBound + Math.floor(Math.random() * (upperBound - lowerBound));
  }

  function highlight(i, j) {
    highlights = [];
    if (i !== undefined) {
      highlights[i] = 'green';
    }
    if (j !== undefined) {
      highlights[j] = 'red';
    }
  }
}

sketch = new p5(merge_sort);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```